# 100-1000 public IP addresses per instance in public cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, ip-address, azure-networking

I'd like to run an instance which can be accessed via 100-1000 different public addresses. It can be either IPv4 or IPv6. Is this possible to do in any public cloud currently? Preferably one of the known providers like AWS/Azure/GCP/DigitalOcean/Rackspace etc, but others are fine as well - just as long as it can be done on a pay-per-use basis.

What's the best way to go about without applying to ISP or dealing with networking infrastructure equipments.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does your service need that many IP addresses per instance, or are you looking to solve a different problem by throwing IP addresses at it? (Ref: The XY problem, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: No, I'm considering this as a way to optimize. We already run 100s of nodes that need to be exposed publicly separately. However, their collective CPU usage can easily fit in a single node.

Comment: And SNI is not an option? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (Again, just asking; I don't know the answer to your actual question).

Comment: As far as I understand, SNI is only relevant when higher layers are involved that make use of hostnames? For us, this is a bit more primitive using raw addresses and operates over TCP, not HTTP(s). Thank you for the suggestion though - I don't even know why other people down vote it :(  - guessing they probably misread the question or arrived at misleading conclusions prematurely.

Comment: Do you need the same port for the service? If not there may be some combination of public IP and range of ports... Anyway in case IPv6 is and option it would not be an issue. It has been already answered this way but I think it is not an issue to get /64 on IPv6. May be not in the webform but contacting technical support would be ok ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IPv6 you can assign whole prefix to a single machine (e.g. /92 which would mean that the machine could handle a whole IPv4 Internet's worth of addresses). By this I means a single "address" entry on an interface for the whole range, not multiple addresses on an interface or multiple interfaces.

Even if the existing cloud providers won't give you a range that large at the moment you can use somebody like Hurricane Electric to give you a /64 (and possibly a /48) range that can be delivered over a tunnel to a single IPv4 address.

Also see this for details about how to write apps on Linux that bind to the prefix https://labs.apnic.net/?p=857

Comment: I think this should do it. Thank you!